# What are the real-life areas of implementing Simplex Method of Linear programming?

Tags: simplex, operations-research

I would like to find some **more or less detailed descriptions** of real-life problems that can be successfully solved by Simplex method.

Could anyone give me some references to the materials where I can find the descriptions of real-life tasks where Simplex method can be used successfully?

I don't need any theoretical materials as I have finished Operations research post-graduate study in my university so I definitely know some theory about this method.

In theory Simplex can be used in a lot of areas. 
I would like to know **in** **what tasks Simplex is currently used in the world**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Simplex algorithm can be used a lot of areas, like you said.

Here is an example of an energy system model, which optimizes over costs of the energy system, which needs to satisfy the given demand.

In theory if you apply this model to energy generation of a country(with real input file from the country), you may find the cheapest option to satisfy the demand with generating power from various types of power plants.

https://github.com/tum-ens/urbs

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Pretty good example.

Answer (score -3):

As a CEO and founder of a company which basically deal with operations research problems, I can tell you that linear programming an amazing tool to solve industrial and enterprise problems.

You can find some detailed examples in the book.

"Linear Programming and Network Flows" from Mokhtar S. Bazaraa, John J. Jarvis, Hanif D. Sherali

All these examples are used in industries (sometimes with some changes) and are crucial to reduce production costs and improve the efficiency of the company.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a good book for students of Operation research faculties fully with a lot of theory that I also went through in my university. If you solve real-world tasks and projects of your clients in this field may be you can share some real links or materials of real project with live problem or task, conditions, client expectations and finally what was done to receive successful result and what improvement and value were received by the client. Such description might have real value for all interested in the field.